# When using strtotime in my function it returns false (1st Jan 1970)?

Tags: php, function, date, strtotime

When using strtotime in my function it returns false (1st Jan 1970)?

This is where I am using strtotime. I need to use week in my strtotime FYI.
Any ideas people?

```
$year  = '2016';
$month = '01';

$weekStart = date('W', strtotime($year . '-' . $month . '-01'));

echo $weekStart;


    for ($weekNumber=0;$weekNumber<=$weekEnd;$weekNumber++)
{
    runTheScript($weekNumber,$month,$weekStart,$weekEnd,$link,$limit,$standardTarget,0,$year);
}
```

Comment: @fvu You forgot the last `;` in your edit :)

Comment: Works fine for me, outputs `53`.

Comment: 53 here too. What OS are you running on? What is your locale?

Comment: And which PHP version?

Comment: Sorry im new to this. See coded added cant add full function as its to big etc. when i start at week 0 I get 1st Jan 1970 when I want 1st Jan 2016.

Comment: What does `runTheScript()` do? How is it related to the code lines above?

Comment: loops through weeks of the year all 52 but i need to start from week 0. So would be the 1st to the 3rd. The rest are fine week 1 shows 4th to 10th etc

Comment: but starting at 0 returns 1st Jan 1970 to 3rd Jan 2016

Comment: man you're starting to mix up things here. If you add code then add the relevant function as well. Most probably you already understood alone that the loop should start from 1 instead of 0, and it makes sense, as on 1st Jan we're in the 1st week of the year

Answer (score 1):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date:

The first week of a year is the week that contains the first Thursday of the year (and, hence, always contains 4 January).

Comment: How can I get the first 3 days then?

Comment: You just got it: 53. That's the 53rd week of 2015

Comment: I get - week - 53 start -28th Dec 2015 end - 31st Dec 2015

Comment: 31st Dec 2015 is Thursday, so that week ends on Sunday 2nd Jan 2016

Comment: if I start at week 0 i get  week:00  start:1st Jan 1970 end:3rd Jan 2016 its all good apart from the start year.

Comment: Its like it wont skip over to the new year on week 53

Comment: I sorry, but that's the definition ISO agreed on, I can't change that for you. If you want your own definition, then you can write your own code that deviates from the standard as you wish

Answer (score 0):

```
for ($weekNumber=1;$weekNumber<=$weekEnd;$weekNumber++) { /* Your Stuff */ }
```

Comment: that gives me - week:01 - start:4th Jan 2016 - end:10th Jan 2016 ....... Im missing the first 3 days of the year